# What is an eigenmatrix and what is its use?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I stumbled upon a paper using the term `eigenmatrix` which I never heard of before. Sadly I found little to none literature to it. Even my books at home don't know the term.

I believe that an eigenmatrix $E$ of some $(n\times n)$ matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ is of form:

$E=\begin{align}\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0  \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_n 
\end{array}\right)\end{align} $ where each $\lambda_i$ is represented as often as its multiplicity.

If my definition up to this point is correct, my questions are:

1. What is this matrix used for?
2. How does it look like if $A$ doesn't have a full set of (real)
   eigenvalues?
3. Do eigenvectors play any role, if so what? (I ask this primarily because the paper I read states that "$E$ is an eigenmatrix of $A$ corresponding to an eigenvector.")
4. How can one calculate an eigenmatrix of some square matrix $A$?

If my definition wasn't correct, feel free to tell me what an eigenmatrix is.

Comment: An eigenmatrix $M$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ for an operator $F$ is just an eigenvector living in a vector space whose elements themselves happened to be matrices such that $F(M) = \lambda M$.  See also: [eigenfunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfunction)

Comment: @JMoravitz this seems kind of helpful. You say $M$ is corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Can $M$ also correspond to an eigenvector? I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: $M$ *is* the eigenvector.  "Eigenfunction", "Eigenmatrix", "Eigenvector"... these are all synonyms with the only distinction between them being that they carry some connotation about what space the vector lives in, be it a function-space, a matrix-space, or just a more generic vector space.

Comment: My mistake. The obvious is sometimes overlooked. Thank you!

Comment: Now... it may be the case that your eigenmatrix (*being an eigenvector of some operator that maps a matrix space $\mathcal{M}$ to a matrix space $\mathcal{M}'$*) may also when interpreted as an operator from some other vector space $U$ to $U'$ have eigenvectors of its own.  Those don't need to have anything to do with the fact that it is itself an eigenmatrix however

Comment: The term is just wrong. The only proper terms are eigenvector, eigenvalue and eigenspace. One should not replace the nouns here by another one just because the value/vector/space in question happens to also be something else, like saying eigenreal if an eigenvalue is real, or eigenline if an eigenspace has dimension $1$; that is just creating needless confusion. So even for an operator acting on a space of matrices or functions, its eigenvectors are just eigenvectors, since they are so only in the role of vectors of that space, not particularly as matrices resp. functions.

Comment: The most trivial eigenmatrix is an $n\times n$ matrix composed of a unique eigenvector as its column. That eigenmatrix doesn't have mutch use because only span a 1D vector space. In a space of infinite dimension is more interesting; the derivative operator $D$ has as eigenvector $e^{ax}$, which is a Taylor series of the operator $x\cdot$, that has its own eigenvectors, the Dirac delta function $\delta (x-a)$. So in this case, the exponential function is the "eigenmatrix" or "eigenoperator" of $D$

Answer (score 1):

The only eigenmatrix application that I know is it's use in Independent Component Analysis (ICA). There is an algorithm for ICA which is called Joint Approximate Diagonalization of Eigenmatrices (JADE) which diagonalizes a 4-dimentional cumulant $N\times N\times N\times N$ tensor $\boldsymbol Q$ by the diagonalization of it's eigenmatrices where an eigenmatrix is a $N\times N$ matrix defined as:

$$\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol M)=\lambda\boldsymbol M$$

where $\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol M)$ is a linear transformation of a matrix defined by the 4-dimentional tensor as:

$$[\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol M)]_{ij}=\sum_{ij}m_{kl}q_{ijkl}$$

In this case, the eigenmatrix of a 4D tensor can be easely found by any standard eigendecomposition algorithm if you reshape the $N\times N\times N\times N$ tensor to a $N^2\times N^2$ matrix then find it's $N^2$-dimentional eigenvectors which can be reshaped to $N\times N$ matrices and became the eigenmatrices of the 4D tensor.

More details can be found on chapter 11 of this [book](https://doi.org/10.1002/0471221317)